# Add cypress code coverage to react project created without cra

Tags: reactjs, cypress

I have React project created without cra. I need to add code coverage for cypress e2e tests.

In app created with cra I do the [**following**](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/tooling/code-coverage#Install-the-plugin) instructions for add code coverage. And add this line of code in `package.json`

```
"start": "react-scripts -r @cypress/instrument-cra start",
```

This work's well with cra.
But in app without cra I can't add `react-scripts` or `@cypress/instrument-cra` for get code coverage information.

How to realize this?

My current configuration ->

**babel.config.json**

```
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-env",
    [
      "@babel/preset-react", 
      {
        "runtime": "automatic"
      }
    ],
    "@babel/preset-typescript"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "istanbul",
    "transform-class-properties",
    [
      "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime",
      {
        "useESModules": true,
        "regenerator": false
      }
    ]
  ],
  "env": {
    "development": {
      "plugins": ["istanbul", "transform-class-properties"]
    },
    "test": {
      "presets": [
        ["@babel/preset-env", {
          "targets": "current node"
        }]
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**e2e.ts**

```
// Import commands.js using ES2015 syntax:
import "@cypress/code-coverage/support";
import './commands'

// Alternatively you can use CommonJS syntax:
// require('./commands')

Cypress.on('uncaught:exception', () => {
  /** 
   * Returning false here prevents Cypress from 
   * failing the test when one of requests fails
   */ 
  return false
});
```

**package.json**

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-cli serve --port 9007 --env currentEnv=local",
    "build": "webpack --mode production",
    "serve": "serve dist -p xxxx",
    "clean": "rm -rf dist",
    "test": "cross-env BABEL_ENV=test jest",
    "cy:open": "cypress open",
    "cy:run": "cypress run",
    "pretest:e2e:run": "npm run build",
    "test:e2e:run": "start-server-and-test start http://localhost:9000 cy:run",
    "test:e2e:dev": "start-server-and-test start http://localhost:9000 cy:open",
    "watch-tests": "cross-env BABEL_ENV=test jest --watch",
    "check:coverage": "nyc report --reporter=text-summary --check-coverage",
    "prepare": "husky install"
  },
  // ...
  "nyc": {
    "all": true,
    "excludeAfterRemap": true,
    "check-coverage": true,
    "extension": [
      ".tsx"
    ],
    "include": [
      "src/views/**/*.tsx"
    ]
  }
```

**cypress.config.ts**

```
export default defineConfig({
  e2e: {
      setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
        // implement node event listeners here,
        require("@cypress/code-coverage/task")(on, config);

        // include any other plugin code...

        // It's IMPORTANT to return the config object
        // with any changed environment variables
        return config;
      },
    video: false,
    baseUrl: "http://localhost:3000/",
  },
});
```

Currently, in browser after each test does finished I get the following error

> Could not find any coverage information in your application by looking at the window coverage object. Did you forget to instrument your application? See code-coverage#instrument-your-application [@cypress/code-coverage]

[image]

Comment: is there any particular reason for using `@cypress/instrument-cra`? I've also made Cypress work with Vue before. The default cypress does not require CRA at all. If it is still not viable, could you provide minimal reproducible git repo? I can fix it up with explanation.

Comment: Shouldn't you add the `instabul` plugin to the `test` environment as well ?

Comment: Check this one ,It will help you https://softans.com/question/add-cypress-code-coverage-to-react-project-created-without-cra/#comment-479